# No ejecutar funciones duplicadas en Javascript, posible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy intentando bloquear que se repita la ejecución de varias funciones que poseen el mismo nombre y básicamente, están clonadas.

Esto no es para una web, sino sería algo fácil de controlar, el tema está en que cada módulo que yo saco en una página que es html, posee sus divs con sus clases, funciones, y ...como si fuera un iframe, pero entre si ellos pueden 'leer' lo que el otro tiene.

Entonces necesito aislar de alguna forma que cada módulo no interactue con otros a pesar de ser idénticos.

Se que es difícil de comprender, pero, habría alguna manera? De comprobar si hay por ejemplo tres funciones con el mismo nombre, evitar que se ejecute tres veces y sólo una?.

Mil gracias!.

Comment: Si que es difícil de comprender, te invito a leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Si, voy a intentar hacerlo de forma más precisa, disculpad las molestias :)

Comment: Si tres funciones tienen el mismo nombre y se llama a una, no se ejecuta 3 veces (o las tres funciones), sólo se ejecuta una vez la última función que se declaro (que sobreescribe a las anteriores).

Comment: Eso es lo que sucede en un entorno normal, pero sin embargo, por poner un ejemplo... hago click en un div y se cambia la clase, y está la función tres veces, es como si tres veces hiciese click. En éste caso no pasaría nada porque con el stopImmediatePropagation() subsano éste problema.

Comment: si tus funciones se declaran en un scope aislado de windows, no habria problema y aislarias tus funciones. Al parecer no es así y tus funciones (con nombres repetidos) viven en window? la solucion mas rapida es sin duda auislar tus funciones en un scope distinto, algo asi !function(){
//scope de definicion de tus funciones y variables que vera solo tu modulo X
}()... espero te ayude... quiza entendi mal lo que querias...

Answer (score 2):

Una practica que me ha ayudado bastante en casos como estos, es darle a cada modulo un nombre y comenzar los nombres de las funciones como Main, con el nombre del modulo, por ejemplo, si le puse "calendario", le doy como nombre a mi funcion ==> calendarioMain(), asi no entra en conflicto con otras funciones que tenga creadas porque nunca le voy a poner a un modulo igual que uno anterior. Otro proceso un poco mas avanzado que puedes hacer es centralizarlo todo en un objeto, todas las funciones y demás, de modo que lo agregues al inicio y de igual forma, no va a entrar en conflicto. Una convencion que se tiene para este tipo de objetos es que el nombre vaya con mayúscula. Un ejemplo de esto es el motor de plantillas javascript llamado Handlebars.